# PdfLaTex: Equation Problem When Using Elsevier Template

Tags: equations, templates, els-cas

I'm trying to use the Elsevier template from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates, but I meet a problem when I try to crossref an equation, the results become `Eq. (1)` like the below pic:

[image: A]

I want it to have a smaller gap between `Eq.` and `(1)` like:

[image]

But I don't know what to do. I had already tried `\Crefname{equation}{}{}`. Is this because of the size of the space?

A minimum example is shown below, pls use it to replace `cas-dc-template.tex` downloaded from the website.

```
% -------------------------------- Class -------------------------------- %

\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

% If the frontmatter runs over more than one page
% use the longmktitle option.

% \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,longmktitle]{cas-dc}

% -------------------------------- And -------------------------------- %

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand \stmauthors { } 
{
    \group_begin:
    \stmAuthorSetup { type = authors }
    \l_stm_au_setup_tl
    \par \vskip\l_stm_augroup_before_dim
    \l_stm_augroup_align_tl
    \l_stm_augroup_size_tl
    \l_stm_augroup_shape_tl
    \l_stm_augroup_weight_tl
    \color{ \l_stm_augroup_color_tl }
    \bool_if:NTF \g_stm_augr_bool
    { \seq_use:Nn \g_stm_augr_seq { \par } }
    {
        \seq_use:cnnn { g_stm_au\int_use:N\g_stm_augr_int _seq }
        { ,~ } { ,~ } { ,~ }
    }
    \par\vskip\l_stm_augroup_after_dim
    \group_end:
}   
\ExplSyntaxOff

% -------------------------------- Packages -------------------------------- %

% \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
% \usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Add
\usepackage{bbding} % Add
\usepackage{color} % Add
\usepackage{caption,setspace} % Add
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % Add
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{longtable}

% \usepackage{times} % Times

% \usepackage{helvet} % Arial
% \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}

%%%Author macros
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
%%%

\begin{document}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={Fig.},labelsep=period} % Add

\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.} % For Fig.
% \Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}
\Crefname{equation}{}{}

\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}

\shorttitle{Short Title}
\shortauthors{A et al}
\title [mode = title]{Title}

% -------------------------------- Authors -------------------------------- %

\author[a]{Author}
\credit{Conceptualization} % Credit authorship

% -------------------------------- Abstract -------------------------------- %

\begin{abstract}
B
\end{abstract}

% -------------------------------- Introduction -------------------------------- %
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{1}

Eq.~\Cref{eq1}

\begin{equation}
This is an equation.
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

%% Loading bibliography style file
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}

% Loading bibliography database
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

Thanks to everyone in advance, have a nice day!

Comment: Quick and dirty but avoids messing with Elesevier's files. Try putting  \frenchspacing at the begining of your document.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work :(

Comment: OK: I realize that somehow, the class have \frenchspacing in force. But when I compile a minimal example with the class, I cannot reproduce your huge gap.

Answer (score 1):

As near as I can tell, the problem is caused *by* using `\Crefname{equation}{}{}`, and is not specific to the Elsevier template; I get it even using the `article` class.

If you leave the behavior as default, or use `\Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}`, it looks OK, in either document class.

Really, the problem is with the `cleverref` package, as `\`  or `~` should never lead to an inter-sentence space, but they do with this option to `\Crefname`. (I suppose this has to do with the fact that you'd normally only use `\Cref` as opposed to `\cref` at the beginning of a sentence.)

However, if the issue is that you *don't* want a word like "Equation" or "Eq." included in the hyperlinked references, and don't just want to use `\ref` because you want the parentheses to be in the hyperlink, I suggest redefining `\equationautorefname` from the hyperlink package, and not using cleverref.

(EDIT: Or remove the `nameinlink` option to cleverref?)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\def\equationautorefname~#1\null{(#1)\null}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % Add

\begin{document}

Default behavior:

\Cref{eq1} (Looks fine.)

\bigskip

Using `\texttt{\textbackslash Crefname\{equation\}\{Eq.\}\{Eqs.\}}'
\Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}

\Cref{eq1} (Looks fine.)

\bigskip

Using `\texttt{\textbackslash Crefname\{equation\}\{\}\{\}}'
\Crefname{equation}{}{}

Eq.~\Cref{eq1} (Big gap.)

Eq.\ \Cref{eq1} (Big gap.)

Eq.\ (\ref{eq1}) (Spacing is fine, but parentheses not in hyperlink.)

Eq.~\autoref{eq1} (Looks fine.)

Eq.\ \autoref{eq1} (Looks fine.)


\bigskip

\begin{equation}
x + y = z
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to reproduce the problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} 
\Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}
\begin{document}
\Cref{eq1} vs Eq. \eqref{eq1} vs Eq. (\ref{eq1}) vs Eq.~(\ref{eq1})

\frenchspacing

\Cref{eq1} vs Eq. \eqref{eq1} vs Eq. (\ref{eq1}) vs Eq.~(\ref{eq1})

\nonfrenchspacing

\Cref{eq1} vs Eq. \eqref{eq1} vs Eq. (\ref{eq1}) vs Eq.~(\ref{eq1})

\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
a = b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

On the first two lines, I do not see any huge gap.

Comment: Thanks! Let me try it.